# Why is this ERD Entity one to many?

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, erd

This is my assignment: Now is your chance to create a full ERD from scratch. We would like you to create a web application that allows users to see a list of books (each with title and author name). Furthermore, the users should be allowed to save a list of their own favourite books.

And the picture below is the solution.

[image]

Looking at the solution, I can understand that one author can have written many books. And one book can be inside many favourites. But one user inside many favourites? Shouldn't users and favourites be a one to one relationship? One user has one favourites list?

Comment: A single book can be the favourite of many users. Or, to put it the other way, many users can favourite the same book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation between **books** and **users** is N:M which is many to many and is implemented with associative entity (a table between) called **favourites**. This is how you normally implement N:M relation between two entities: by creating a "bridge" table to which both of your tables have 1:N relation (one to many).

In your case, one user can favourite many books just like one book can be favourited by many users. This implies a candidate key within table **favourites** that consists of primary keys for **books** and **users** tables, which is (user_id, book_id).

---

If you had 1:1 relationship between **users** and **favourites** table, this would mean that one user can favourite only one book and following that statement you wouldn't need **favourites** table, but instead could put book's primary key within the **users** table making this relation 1:N (between books and users).

Comment: Thank you! It's starting to make sense now. I have one more question just to make sure I get this straight. Why is there an associative table here instead of a many to many relationship with no bridge between?

Comment: There is no possibility to implement many to many relationship without a table in between. This is because if you want one row in users table (here: one user) to have connection with many books (as their favourites) and you put book_id within the users table, then you would only have one favourite book for one user. If you would like to put many rows with book ids then your table users wouldn't identify a user (you identify it as a primary key, because one user is represented by exactly one row) and instead your table would identify one row as connection between one user and one book.